# Cross compiler arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc does not find GLES libraries

Tags: gcc, arm, cross-compiling, raspberry-pi

So when compiled with `gcc` my code compiles successfully with the  *GLES* libraries and headers. When I want to compile using `arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc` for the RPi it can't find *GLES2/gl2.h*.

Does `arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc`  not know about the headers in `usr/include`? It works with headers ib usr/include root such as `stdio.h` or `malloc.h` but when I try and include something in a folder inside *usr/include* it can't find it?

Comment: Your *host/PC* headers are different than the *Raspberry Pi*.  You need to point them to `GLES2/gl2.h` that are configured for your device, the *Raspberry Pi*.  Things may compile with wrong interfaces, etc.  It is always better to use the **real** headers.  Unfortunately, I don't know where you can get them; or I would provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As said you must provide the cross compiler both headers and libs your executable will be linked when run on the device. Which means you have to create a sysroot with both those somewhere, and tell the crosscompiler to use it. You might even dd the sd card you use in your Pi and mount the image on your host pc. That will be your sysroot.
Anyway, I suppose you should read a guide on how to cross build before trying to do random things...

Simpler way might be to compile directly on the device.